# Open previously opened tab in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

I do know that we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for opening next and previous tabs and also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for opening the Nth tab...

But what I am looking for is opening the previously opened tab (Qview in a remote).

Assume that I have 8 tabs open in a window, and I was previously on tab-3. Now I am on tab-7.

Now I need a key-combination that will take me back to tab-3. And once I move to tab-3 hitting the same key combination should bring me back to tab-7.

Comment: I know what you mean, but don't know if this feature is implemented. You can go to a specific tab using `Ctrl-[1-9]` but I don't think you can do what you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native way to do this, but there is an extension called [RecentTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml).

You can configure it to either switch between two last tabs, or display a list of open tabs.

Comment: I liked the option of switching between the last two tabs.